# Alternating color in itemize

Tags: color, itemize

I want to create an automatic itemize environment where the item's color font is alternating.

Suposing the following list:

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item A
   \item B
   \item C
   \item D
   \item E
\end{itemize}
```

I want a code to A, C, and E have color #1 and B and D, color #2.

Yes, I know I can create an alternative \item command (\coloreditem or something such that), but I am asking for an automated way. So, if I insert on the fly a new item between other two items of that list, I do not need to (manually) change the color scheme of every item after the new one.

Answer (score 10):

You can add a custom macro before each `\item` with the `xpatch` package. In the example below the `\choosecolor` macro is defined which alternates the color using a toggle.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newtoggle{tcolor}
\newcommand{\choosecolor}{%
\iftoggle{tcolor}%
{\color{\colorone}\togglefalse{tcolor}}%
{\color{\colortwo}\toggletrue{tcolor}}%
}
\pretocmd{\item}{\choosecolor}{}{}

\begin{document}
\def\colorone{red}
\def\colortwo{blue}
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\end{itemize}
Text after itemize
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: So, in your example, how I am sure that every new itemize list starts with tcolor=true? I think the tcolor toggle does not reset automatically after each itemize list.

EDIT: Nevermind, I just tested and works very fine, reseting the toggle. Thanks :)

Comment: In my nature I always thank from the heart those who help with the heart Sebastiano.

Answer (score 10):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newif\iffirstcoloreditem
\newcommand*\colorizeitemize[2]
  {%
    \LetLtxMacro\itemBAK\item
    \renewcommand*\item[1][]
      {%
        \iffirstcoloreditem
          \firstcoloreditemfalse
          \color{#1}%
        \else
          \firstcoloreditemtrue
          \color{#2}%
        \fi
        \if\relax\detokenize{##1}\relax
          \itemBAK
        \else
          \itemBAK[##1]%
        \fi
      }%
  }

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\colorizeitemize{blue}{red}
\duckitemize
\duckenumerate
\duckdescription
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good choice of colors :)

Comment: @Marijn you too :)

Comment: I did not know the duckuments package. Funnier than lipsum ;)

Comment: @FabianoFagundes no wonder you didn't know, I pushed it to CTAN only a few days ago :)

Comment: This is ducking clever!